# jQuery display input data inside select on click

Tags: jquery, select, input

I have a text input with a button. When I fill in the input and click the button I want to add that information to a select. Please can anyone one help, I can't find an example anywhere.

```
Input & button
<input id="new_menu_name" type="text" name="new_menu_name" placeholder="Please enter your menu title">
<input class="add_menu_item" name="add_menu_item" value="Add" type="button">

Select
<select name="menu_items" id="menu_items" size="8" multiple="multiple" style="height:200px; width:250px;">      
</select>
```

I have tried using this script but with no luck

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add_menu_item").click(function(){
 $('#menu_items').
      append($("<option></option>").
      attr("value").
      text(value)); 
    });
```

JSfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/XDqQL/

Comment: I have updated with a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/XDqQL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `attr`, you're not actually setting a value: you're retrieving the current value of the `value` attribute. You should use the [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val) function to set the value:

```
$(".add_menu_item").click(function () {
    $('#menu_items').append(
        $("<option></option>").val(value).text(value)
    );
});
```

---

Now that I've seen your full code, it's clear that the other problem is that you aren't setting the `value` variable. I think you probably want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XDqQL/1/):

```
$(".add_menu_item").click(function () {
    var value = $(this).prev().val();
    $('#menu_items').append(
        $("<option></option>").val(value).text(value)
    );
});
```

(NB also that I've changed the fiddle to use jQuery rather than Mootools.)

Comment: Hi, thanks I tried this but it still dosent work, here is the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/XDqQL/

Comment: Wow dude, you are the bomb, sorry my bad about the Mootools, I meant to choose jquery, Cheers

Comment: Hi sorry to bug you but I want to add an if statement so it only writes to the select box if the text length is greater than 0. How would I go about that? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try changing `attr("value").text(value)` to `attr("value",value)`

Answer (score 1):

change that to `attr("value", value)`. The `attr("value")` returns the value of the attribute.